# I've read a cosmic string can accelerate a mass. Can someone explain how it works?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-string

In the book [Brief Answers to the Big Questions: the final book from Stephen Hawking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brief_Answers_to_the_Big_Questions_(book)) Hawking describes cosmic strings as follows;

> They are like rubber bands as they are under great tension, something like a hundred billion billion billion tonnes. Cosmic string attached to Sun would accelerate it from nought to sixty in a thirtieth of a second.

What does this mean and what is be unit of "nought to sixty"? kilometers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't possible to attach a cosmic string to the Sun so Hawking does not mean his statement to be taken literally. What he means is the the force required to accelerate the mass of the Sun from $0$ to $60$ miles per hour in one thirtieth of a second is about the same as the tension in a cosmic string.

Side note: in the UK the time taken for a car to accelerate from standstill to $60$ miles per hour has long been a traditional measure of the power of the car. The phrase "0 to 60" is instantly recognisable to any UK car enthusiast, and I'm sure that's why Hawking used it.

$60$ mph is $26.82$ m/s so to accelerate to this speed in $1/30$th of a second is an acceleration of about $800$ m/s$^2$. If we multiply this by the mass of the Sun, $\approx 2 \times 10^{30}$ kg then we find the force needed to do this is a shade over $10^{33}$ Newtons.

Hawking describes the tension in a cosmic string as:

> a hundred billion billion billion tonnes

which is $10^{33}$ Newtons. So this is the same as the force required to accelerate the Sun that we calculated above.